# System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed

Tags: c#

I have got following error in my following code:

> Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed.

I test my code number of time but I have not found where is mistake in my code. Can anyone tell me where is my code incorrect or why this error occurs?

```
   /*start calculate grade of SA2 */
   SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
   con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con1"].ConnectionString;
    if (Convert.ToString(ddlexam.SelectedItem) == "SA2")
    {


        int SA2;
        string grade = null;
        SqlCommand comm;
        SqlDataReader dr;
        con.Open();
        comm = new SqlCommand("select SA2 from terms_marks where admission_no=@admission_no and sub_id=@sub_id", con);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sub_id", sub_id);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@admission_no", admission_no);
        dr = comm.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            SA2 = Convert.ToInt32(dr["SA2"].ToString());
            markspercentage = (SA2 * 100) / maxmarks;
            if (markspercentage >= 91 && markspercentage <= 100)
            {
                grade = "A1";
            }
            else if ((markspercentage >= 81) && (markspercentage <= 90))
            {
                grade = "A2";
            }
            else if (markspercentage >= 71 && markspercentage <= 80)
            {
                grade = "B1";
            }
            else if (markspercentage >= 61 && markspercentage <= 70)
            {
                grade = "B2";
            }
            else if (markspercentage >= 51 && markspercentage <= 60)
            {
                grade = "C1";
            }
            else if (markspercentage >= 41 && markspercentage <= 50)
            {
                grade = "C2";
            }
            else if (markspercentage >= 33 && markspercentage <= 40)
            {
                grade = "D";
            }
            else if (markspercentage >= 21 && markspercentage <= 32)
            {
                grade = "E1";
            }
            else if (markspercentage >= 0 && markspercentage <= 20)
            {
                grade = "E2";
            }
        }
        dr.Close();
        cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "CreategradeDetails";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@st_id", st_id);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@roll_no", roll_no);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@admission_no", admission_no);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sub_id", sub_id);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FA1", DBNull.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FA2", DBNull.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SA1", DBNull.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total_FirstTerm", DBNull.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FA3", DBNull.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FA4", DBNull.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SA2", grade);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total_SecondTerm", DBNull.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total_FA", DBNull.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total_SA", DBNull.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GrandTotal", DBNull.Value);

        result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

    }
    /*end calculate SA2 grade */
    /* start calculate Total_SecondTerm grade;*/
    if (Convert.ToString(ddlexam.SelectedItem) == "SA2")
    {
        int TotalST;
        string grade = null;
        SqlCommand comm;
        SqlDataReader dr;
        con.Open();
        comm = new SqlCommand("select Total_SecondTerm from terms_marks where admission_no=@admission_no and sub_id=@sub_id", con);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sub_id", sub_id);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@admission_no", admission_no);
        dr = comm.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            TotalST = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Total_SecondTerm"].ToString());
            dr.Close();
            comm = new SqlCommand("select Total_SecondTerm from max_marks where admission_no=@admission_no and sub_id=@sub_id", con);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sub_id", sub_id);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@admission_no", admission_no);
            if (dr.Read())
            {
                total_STmaxmarks = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Total_SecondTerm"].ToString());
                secondterm_percentage = (TotalST * 100) /total_STmaxmarks;


            }
            dr.Close();
            if (secondterm_percentage >= 91 && secondterm_percentage <= 100)
            {
                grade = "A1";
            }
            else if ((secondterm_percentage >= 81) && (secondterm_percentage <= 90))
            {
                grade = "A2";
            }
            else if (secondterm_percentage >= 71 && secondterm_percentage <= 80)
            {
                grade = "B1";
            }
            else if (secondterm_percentage >= 61 && secondterm_percentage <= 70)
            {
                grade = "B2";
            }
            else if (secondterm_percentage >= 51 && secondterm_percentage <= 60)
            {
                grade = "C1";
            }
            else if (secondterm_percentage >= 41 && secondterm_percentage <= 50)
            {
                grade = "C2";
            }
            else if (secondterm_percentage >= 33 && secondterm_percentage <= 40)
            {
                grade = "D";
            }
            else if (secondterm_percentage >= 21 && secondterm_percentage <= 32)
            {
                grade = "E1";
            }
            else if (secondterm_percentage >= 0 && secondterm_percentage <= 20)
            {
                grade = "E2";
            }

        }

        dr.Close();
        cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "CreategradeDetails";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@st_id", st_id);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@roll_no", roll_no);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@admission_no", admission_no);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sub_id", sub_id);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FA1", DBNull.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FA2", DBNull.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SA1", DBNull.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total_FirstTerm", DBNull.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FA3", DBNull.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FA4", DBNull.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SA2", DBNull.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total_SecondTerm", grade);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total_FA", DBNull.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total_SA", DBNull.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GrandTotal", DBNull.Value);

        result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

    }
    /* end calculate Total_SecondTerm grade;*/
```

error in above code here

```
  comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sub_id",sub_id);   
  comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@admission_no", admission_no);
      if(dr.Read())                           
       {
     total_STmaxmarks = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Total_SecondTerm"].ToString());
```

Comment: Next time, please search your problem in Google first.

Comment: As a side note, you should refactor duplicate code (example the nested `if`'s) into a method that takes the percentage and returns a grade, maybe , `string GetGrade(int mark);`

Answer (score 2):

The issue is here:

```
dr.Close();  //Here
cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandText = "CreategradeDetails";
```

You have closed the connection before the reader reads it. The reader will read only when the connection is open.

Comment: thanks for are your reply issue is resolve

Answer (score 1):

You are closing the reader on this line:

```
dr.Close();
```

Then four lines later, you're doing this:

```
if (dr.Read())
```

The error message is pretty clear: you can't use the reader after you close it.

Note that this is the *second* instance of `dr` that you are using, not the first one -- it's the instance you create inside the if block where you have the comment:

```
/*end calculate SA2 grade */
/* start calculate Total_SecondTerm grade;*/
```

My suggestion would be that you clean up your code a little bit to reduce confusion that leads to problems and makes it harder to find them.  Also, you should make use of [the `using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) with classes that implement the disposable pattern, like `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection`, `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand`, and `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader`.  For example, here's a clean way to write code for interacting with a data reader:

```
using (var conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(usingConnectionString))
{
    using (var command = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(usingQuery, conn))
    {
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // do your work here...
        }
    }
}
```

Notice I don't ever call `Close` because that's done automatically once the code exists the `using` scope.